# How to create a custom property/method inside a MovieClip? (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, movieclip

I'm programming a kind of "Lights Off" game in Flash Professional (not Flash/Flex Builder)
and it would be very nice if I could manage on/off state in a grphically designed Symbol like this:

```
square1.on();
/* calling this method produces the same as */
square1.on = true;
square1.gotoAndStop("onState");

/* obviously, the next method: */
square1.off();
/* will produce */
square1.on = false;
square1.gotoAndStop("offState");
```

Is this possible? How do I create the custom `on` property and custom methods `on()` and `off()`? If not possible, what else can I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a property like `state` and create two functions to change that state and navigate the playhead.

Also, you should be extending MovieClip to create these custom properties... better practice.

```
class MySquare extends MovieClip {
    public function on ():void {
        this.state = 'on';
        this.gotoAndStop('onState');
    }
    public function off ():void {
        // same, but for off
    }
```

[[Tutorial] Export for ActionScript](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/movieclips_classes_AS3_pg1.htm)

Comment: You didn't understand me. I already have a MovieClip designed graphically in the Library, and I want to add the custom property and the two methods. I've edited the question so there's no confusion.

Comment: Did you export the symbol for ActionScript and assign a custom class?

Comment: No. But would the symbol keep its graphics if I extend it?

Comment: Yes. See the linked tutorial in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own class, that extends MovieClip like this:

```
public class CustomMovieclip extends MovieClip
{
   public function CustomMovieclip() {
     //constructor, here you do any initialization stuff
   {

   public function on() {
     //here you turn on the lights
   {

   public function off() {
     //here you turn off the lights
   {
}
```

And then you can simply call them like this:

```
var bulb = new CustomMovieclip();
bulb.off();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a movie clip called btn1 for which I needed a custom property "sel" (for selected state)

This is how I used it.

```
btn1.sel = 1;
```

You can also add new properties like

```
btn1.name = "Prabhat";
```

Or

```
btn1.selected = false;
```

Hope this helps.. although i see its a quite old post..just in case if you still need the info